# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.2.0' not found

Tags: java, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm currently making a Spigot plugin and to build this plugin, I use the Lifecycle Package build. The Spigot Plugin I'm making is actually an API so naturally I would want to include JavaDocs with it. The thing is, I already made the JavaDocs, I know just *think* I need to put the maven-javadoc-plugin in my build and my reporting. However, whenever I reload maven changes, I get errors when I build saying *Plugin `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.2.0' not found`. This is quite unfortunate because I've looked up documentation on this plugin for both the plugin under `<reporting>` and `<build>`. I honestly think the probably is solely in my `pom.xml` but I don't know for sure. Here's my pom (I'm only going to show you sections of my pom for privacy reasons):

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If anyone could help me that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

u can build like this

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <additionalparam>
                                -Xdoclint:none
                            </additionalparam>
                        </configuration>  
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what did you change, and why this should works ?